# Remove reverb and soundproof room

Tags: sound-proofing, noise, noise-reduction, acoustic, sounds

I have a room I'd like to be able to record in, and I'm looking at foam panels and various items to influence the sound quality/propagation/acoustic, etc.

Thing is, the more I read about it, the more I realize I have absolutely no clue what I'm doing. I need someone with experience and knowledge to help me out.

I have a relatively squarish room and I would like to accomplish, as much as possible, the following :

- Remove reverb / echo for better voice recording quality.
- Make it so outside sounds are not hearable inside the room
- Make it so inside sounds are not hearable from outside the room
- I would like to be able for this to cost less than or about 500€

I have seen a billion different panels and I have *no clue* what to use. I've seen people place bass traps in corners, other use the same panels everwhere, others even place only a couple of panels here and there.

I was thinking of buying a little of all panels but that seems rather idiotic.

I know there are millions of parameter to take into account, but I don't specifically need a studio quality (if I can that's great).

The current situation is the following :

- Room is under the roof and about 3.5m x 3.5m
- Two opposite walls are vertical, two opposite walls are angled after about 1m from the ground. Both angles (due to the roof) are not the same on each side, and therefore not the same length either.
- Room has one small window, on one of the angled roof-walls
- Room has 1 door
- Room is made of plaster and wood (mostly plaster)
- Ground is made of wood

Reverb is rather insane ; currently room is empty. I've recorded a small video (not meant to show the room, more meant to have a memory of how it sounded before I placed my acoustic mods), here it is : 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mszS2X7CDFgL02HJP7NqBhK-Uih_SReh/view?usp=sharing

You can have a good look of the room there which might help you. The video is really just me talking to the cam saying nothing interesting, for the sake of making sound in that room.

Here are the relevant sounds :

- Want to avoid recording : Wife walking around in the house
- Want to avoid recording : TV a couple of rooms away (barely hearable from there already, even with full sensitivity mic)
- Want to avoid recording : Rain/wind sounds on the window
- Want to avoid spreading : my voice when I'm recording. I might be close to yelling sometimes.

I will probably never have deep bass or stuff like that and I don't intend to record music, it will always be my voice, at all times. So the frequency range should be easier to manage, I hope.

I have also installed a software that I thought would help, called EQ Room Wizard, but I am not experienced enough in acoustics to use it (at all).

Now from what I've found, thomann provides a lot of choice and information on what you can buy ; amazon too but less. I've found various prices and types, and looked it up a bit. Thing is, like I said, I don't know what type of foam I need to buy. I see keywords/acronyms like SA, WAS, SN, Wedge, and numbers all over which I have no idea what they mean.

I really need someone to tell me the basics that will give best result vs time/money invested. Like : "buy 4 panels of that type and put them near window, then fill the walls with that other type of panel, and put xxx close to the ground."

I'm making things up obviously, but what I mean is, I don't want you gusy to give me a millimeter answer (unless you wanna somehow spend the time to make this the perfect studio)

I have given as much information as possible, feel free to ask more questions if necessary.

I hope that was enough !

And of course, thank you very much for even reading this far

Comment: start with a thick plush rug and heavy drapes/curtains. add needed furnishings. then spend money.

Comment: Rock wool insulation does a great job of soundproofing. You'd want to cover every wall and ceiling, and ideally the floor too.

Comment: Floor is already 80% carpet, I'm sure it helps. I've been told about rock wool but I don't like it. It requires me to make the frames and everything myself, which I'd rather not. It's also quite volatile & really toxic to breathe, which I will do a lot since I'll spend a lot of time in that room.

On the other hand, the "spikes" are pretty aesthetic.

Comment: Building a room within a room yourself using sound deadening insulation (e.g. Roxul safe n sound rockwool insulation) and then using isolating clips/isolating glue on double layers of drywall is likely the cheapest and best generic answer you will get on this site to get the near totally soundproof results you are after. Beyond that, filling the room with normal furniture, carpeting, etc. should have the desired effect of eliminating reverb. A few panels on their own will get rid of reverb, but I doubt you'd get soundproof unless you cover every square inch of the room.

Comment: Just remember, soundproofing and acoustic damping are two different things, which needs to be dealt with separately.